# Is it possible to compile and run the dlib library on embedded devices with ARM Cortex-M7 processors?

Tags: arm, embedded, dlib, mbed

I have just started using the amazing dlib library in Visual Studio and I have been able to compile and run the face detection examples. I was wondering if it would be possible to compile and run the library on an Mbed device, such as this [one](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Discovery-F769NI/), with an [M7](https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-m7) (or other M-series) processor. In other words, what specifications should I look out for to determine whether a microcontroller can, if at all, run dlib. Note that Mbed devices run C++ code, so it would be possible to copy and paste the source code of dlib and compile it, but I want to know if this is possible before I purchase a board. Also, if the RAM and ROM of the board are not enough, I can always attach external RAM/ROM.

Alternatively, if anyone knows of a library that can perform face detection or recognition on an embedded device, I would be happy to hear it.

Thanks.

Comment: "Run C++" is a pretty broad definition. Professional embedded applications only use a restricted subset of C++.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I want it to "run the library", implying that I want the embedded device to perform face detection or recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the F769 is a considerably powerful embedded device there is no chance that dlib will run on it. Machine learning algorithms, even if not run in real-time, typically require a vast amount of RAM memory, specially for online-learning (learning on the target). You can take a look at ARMs very own [CMSIS NN](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS_Dev/NN/html/index.html) library to see what's currently "state-of-the-art" for devices that size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if I can somehow use this library to perform face recognition or even detection?

Comment: I doubt it. Just to give you an idea ARM has examples of [very crude image recognition](https://developer.arm.com/solutions/machine-learning-on-arm/developer-material/how-to-guides/image-recognition-on-arm-cortex-m-with-cmsis-nn/single-page) where they can classify images in 10 different categories. There's even a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdWi_fvY9Og) of that which I personally already found very impressive, but it's far from actual face recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Tensorflow Lite for Microcontrollers.  You can put these on embedded devices.  Wake words and object detection runs easily on various boards (Arduino Nano 33, SparkFun Edge).  There's a compiler included for Mbed.

Answer (score 0):

Microcontrollers are not suitable for video and image recognition even if you attach external ram. The chip you where suggestiong is top of the line in microcontroller world. But this means only 2Mb for ALL your software and only 512kb of ram onboard. Think of it this way the image you need with enough detail to recoginze someone would be atleast a few mb.

I would suggest that you look at to the application processors of ARM (A series) or [NVIDA Jetson](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded-computing).